Node-RED - How to update the HTML code of a custom ui node when a new message arrives? Dashboard V3.6.2
I am in the process of creating my first node to display a speedometer on the dashboard.
I have the problem that the written HTML code for the custom ui node is not updated when a new message arrives.
Is it possible to change the format parameter of addWidget, e.g. in the node.on function or in the beforeEmit property?
My code is structured according to the following scheme:
module.exports = function(RED) {
  function html(config) {
    var code = String.raw`
    <div>
      <p>text</p>
      <p>${config.var}</p>
    </div>`;
    return code;
  }

  function node(config) {
    var ui = RED.require("node-red-dashboard")(RED);
    RED.nodes.createNode(this, config);
    var done = ui.addWidget({
      format: html(config);
      //defining more properties
    })

    node.on('input', function(msg) {
    //can i update the format parameter here?
    });
  }
  RED.nodes.registerType('ui_node',FirstNode);
}

The result should be that a different HTML code is assigned to the format Parameter of addwidget and the new HTML code with new values is displayed in the dashboard when a new message arrives.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Please also update the question to be clear which version of the Node-RED Dashboard you are working with. At this time I would recommend not writing anything new for node-red-dashboard and targeting @flowfuse/node-red-dashboard.

How does the development of a node with flowfuse work? Can you also use HTML code there?
